# Trying to find distance between two points, but I'm getting wrong answers:(

Tags: c, function, protocols, formula, distance

I am trying to find distance between two points, but the result is off.
If i type in (1,2) and (4,5) I get

Distance = 1.414214

instead of 4.242640

This happens regardless of what numbers I input.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

float distance(float a, float b, float c, float d);

int main()
{
   float a,b,c,d,D;
   printf("Please enter the first x coordinate. x1= ");
   scanf("%f",&a);
   printf("Please enter the first x coordinate. y1= ");
   scanf("%f",&b);
   printf("Please enter the first x coordinate. x2= ");
   scanf("%f",&c);
   printf("Please enter the first x coordinate. y2= ");
   scanf("%f",&d);

   D = distance(a,b,c,d);
   printf("Distance = %f",D);

   return 0;
}

float distance(float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2)
{
float d, D, x, y, X, Y;
x = x1 - x2;
y = y1 - y2;
X = x*x;
Y = y*y;
d = X + Y;
float sqrtf (float d);
return sqrtf(d);
}
```

Comment: `int a,b,c,d,D;` try a `float`. For *all* of these. And turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: you are parsing floats into ints...

Comment: Oh whoops, can't believe I did that! Thank you!! and How do I turn up my compiler warnings?

Comment: ^^ I've only had two weeks of programming, what does wall for gcc mean?

Comment: The distance formula? http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the wrong answer because you're passing the wrong arguments to your function.

> D = distance(a,b,c,d);

Based on your input scanning, you are telling it this:

> D = distance(x1,y1,x2,y2);

However, your function takes a different order of arguments (`x1, x2, y1, y2`).

Change that line to this:

> D = distance(a,c,b,d);

And you should get the right answer.

Comment: It's alright, we all make mistakes! That's how you learn. Anytime (: @rickylance

Answer (score 0):

Look at the variable declaration inside the main function-

> int a,b,c,d,D;

The data type be a float instead of integer.

Comment: Yep! But now i've encountered a new problem! The answer I get is wrong. Close, but still wrong.

Comment: Floating point numbers have only a certain discrete precision. So when you need more precision to calculate you can't use float. Use double data type instead of it.